# Где хранятся настройки?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Пытаюсь добавить в проект на C# настройки (Settings), но на вкладке проекта их нет. Как их туда добавить?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по снимку, проект - для Windows Mobile, а значит, это Compact Framework. А CF, к сожалению, не включает System.Configuration. Поэтому варианты такие:

- хранить настройки в реестре,
- создать свой класс и сериализовать его (например, с помощью XmlSerializer)
- использовать стороннюю библиотечку (типа [nini](http://nini.sourceforge.net/)).